# When getting share count using Facebook graph, I keep getting Application Request limit reached error even though I'm nowhere near the limit

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

Sorry if this has been posted elsewhere but I could not find the correct answer to my question.

I am trying to get  the share count for a page  but I'm getting the error:

{"error":{"message":"(#4) Application request limit reached","type":"OAuthException","is_transient":true,"code":4,"fbtrace_id":"GfwY7+r9UJb"}}

I don't think I'm hitting the limit. You can see the page here - https://moving2canada.com/express-entry-draw/. I know it's being called 3 times at a time but I've changed it so it's calling just once and still same result.

If I am hitting the limit somehow, can I add an access token to increase the limit?

Here is the code:

```
$query_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://moving2canada.com/express-entry-draw/";  
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$social_stats = json_decode($response, true)
return $social_stats
```

Hope I am being clear enough and thanks in advance

Comment: Sure you can add an access token - but general Rate Limits will still apply. Are you executing this on every page load? That is something you should not to do begin with. Cache the result for a reasonable time on your end instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have it set up on a test site now with a new app so I can't be hitting Rate Limits and I still get this error. Im using this now - (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/?id={url}&fields=id&access_token={access_token}).    The only thing I get now is the _ID_ field. When I try to add _shares_ as a field, it gives me an error. Could it be because of this? https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/

Comment: No, `shares` has just been removed a couple of API versions back, in current ones you want to be looking for `engagement` now - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fmoving2canada.com%2Fexpress-entry-draw%2F%26fields%3Dengagement&version=v2.12

Comment: Thank you so much! Been banging my head against the wall all day over this, dont why I didn't come across it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shares` field of the `URL` node has just been removed a couple of API versions back, in current ones you want to be looking for `engagement` now.

Graph API Explorer example for your given URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fmoving2canada.com%2Fexpress-entry-draw%2F%26fields%3Dengagement&version=v2.12